# Can't redirect using 301 and .htacces

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, redirect

I've just begun learning CSS and HTML.

I bought a domain from HostGator to upload my tiny website.

I used CyberDuck to upload all of my things.

Then I found out about a thing called .htacces which I did not have in the WWW folder and I've tried "making" one.

Then I tested the site using Nibbler and it keeps saying "There is duplicate content" and that I should do this: "Choose one domain that you would like to use and then set a permanent (HTTP 301) redirect to forward users who visit the other."

I found a lot of REWRITES AND REDIRECTS but I could not to make any of them work.

What do I need to write to not have a "duplicate" site (or to solve the Canonical Website Address (This is how it's called I think)) ???

Let's say my site name is: http://www.FirstSite.net and I want all "FirstSite" searches to go to https://FirstSite.net or FirstSite.net but still being a https.

I wrote https with an s because I want to make the site secure (if that is even possible).

I've been modifying the .htacces from gator's cPanel and I am using Google Chrome.

Thank you for reading this manuscript !

This is all that I've copy-paste into it (I forgot what those without a # do (the last 2 paragraphs)) :

```html
# MAIN DEFAULTS
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html
DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent



#HTACCES Security
<Files ~ “^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])”>
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>


# 1 WEEK 1 DAY
<filesMatch “.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico)$”>
Header set Cache-Control “max-age=691200, public”
</filesMatch>
# 1 WEEK 1 DAY
<filesMatch “.(xml|txt|js)$”>
Header set Cache-Control “max-age=691200, proxy-revalidate”
</filesMatch>
# 1 WEEK 1 DAY
<filesMatch “.(html|htm|css|php)$”>
Header set Cache-Control “max-age=691200, private, proxy-revalidate”
</filesMatch>

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 1. Dotfiles like .htaccess are hidden files. Make sure hidden files are visible in cPanel.
2. Install SSL certificate to be able to use HTTPS.

Comment: Then what about other redirection ?

Comment: Go to the document root for your domain, and find the .htaccess file that should already be there. Make changes in that file. The redirections will work.

Comment: You can't just redirect **http** to **https**, [you need to get the certificate](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html) first. Once you get the certificate then you can change the DNS on your server to be redirect to **https**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your website secure you must have a valid SSL certificate. It's not just putting `s` with `http`

If you already have one installed with your domain. You can use the code below for you domain address to force SSL(redirect).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstsite\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.firstsite.net/$1 [R,L]
```

To resolve the canonical or duplicate website issue, please use

```
# Fix the non-www to www canonicalization issue:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Fix the canonical issue vecause of index files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . http://www.firstsite.net%1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]+/)*)index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule index\.html$ http://www.firstsite.net/%1 [R=301,L]\
```

Change `firstsite.net` with your domain name and the name and extension of the index file based on your server settings.

**If Using ngnix Server Redirect www to non-www**

> Strip www from url with nginx redirect

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 http://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    ...
    #The rest of your configuration goes here#
}
```

> So you need to have TWO server codes.

Comment: Then what about other redirections ?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeFlorian what kind of redirections you are asking. What redirections do you need?

Comment: The one that fixes the issue that Nibbler pointed out; that there is duplicate content, that there are virtually 2 different websites.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeFlorian I have updated the above answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you but it did not work. Nibbler still says that I have duplicate content.

Comment: georgeflorian.org

Comment: As your website is using the ngnix server; I have added the redirection code for ngnix, you can add these lines to your virtulahost file. 
> .htaccess file for apache servers only

Comment: SO I add :

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 http://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    ...
    #The rest of your configuration goes here#
}


Only to the virtualhost file ?

What about the htacces file ? I let it like it is ?

Comment: I don't know where to find virtualhost file. It's possible that I do not have one. I find it in cPanel in File Manager ?

I also did not have the .htaccess file and I had to make it.

Comment: .htaccess file is not for ngnix server and it's neither supported. You can look for the config. option either in cPanel or contact your server admin/hosting provider